# Loop through input elements that id ends in

Tags: jquery

How can I loop all input elements in JQuery and select only the inputs that the ID attribute ends in a specific name? For example see my html below:

My html is like this

```
<input type="text" id="a-user" value="0"/>
<input type="text" id="a-amount" value="10"/>
<input type="text" id="b-user" value="0"/>
<input type="text" id="b-amount" value="10"/>
......
```

I want to loop all the inputs that the id ends with `-amount` so that i can add a formatting to all those fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("input[id$=-amount]").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/SSPwh/) 
[See This Documentation for reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id$="someName"]').each(function() {
       // Your code here
});
```

use the `$` symbol

[**Ends with Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)